# Why doesn't this print "5"?

Tags: python, function, scope

```
def useless(x):
    print(x)
useless(5)
print(x)
```

Why doesn't the last line of my code print "5" (referring to the function parameter used in line three bound to x)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no variable `x` in that scope. When you called `useless(5)`, you just assigned `x = 5` in the scope of the `useless` function. But when you quit the function, your scope changed and there is simply no `x` defined outside of the function. You can check it with the `locals()` call, it will show you all the assigned variables (even default ones) in your current scope.